# picklist value when change into lost, then today date set of a custom date field which name is stopdate__c

Tags: workflow, formula

how to possible to show the today date when picklist value changed into Lost value like there is three value in picklist first is book second holds and third is Lost. how to possible from the workflow.

the date will show on my custom field which api name is `stopdate__c`

Comment: what did you try so far? Did you have a look at workflow rules?

Comment: This sounds like a very simple workflow rule to implement. It appears that you know the three important pieces of information: 1) which object the workflow should be on.   2) the action that you want to take.   3) the criteria to determine when that action should be executed. If you're not sure where to start, I'd suggest working through [the trailhead unit on workflow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/workflow).